# assembler nasm. После sdq и деления вычитаем из регистра знака число и к результату добавляется 1, почему?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Linux, nasm, ld i386
Вот код:

```
mov eax, -100 ; в регистр eax ложу -100
cdq           ; указываю регистру edx знак eax, то есть в регистре edx теперь 0xFFFFFFFF
mov ebx, -2   ; в ebx ложу -2
idiv ebx      ; делю -100 на -2, теперь в регистре eax лежит 50
PUTCHAR al    ; это макрос, который выводит символ по таблице ascii (через код в регистре), 
              ; в al лежит 50 = 0x32, и выводит символ '2'
PUTCHAR 10    ; макрос выводит символ перевода строки
sub edx, 0xCA ; вычитаю из edx(0xFFFFFFFF) значение 0xCA, вот тут то и вопрос:
PUTCHAR dl    ; по идее 0xFFFFFFFF - 0xCA = 0x35 и это символ '5', 
              ; но мне выдает символ '6', якобы результат вычитания равен 0x36. Почему?
PUTCHAR 10    ; перевод строки
FINISH        ; завершение программы.
```

Если не выполнять деление:

```
mov eax, -100 ; в регистр eax ложу -100
cdq           ; указываю регистру edx знак eax, то есть в регистре edx теперь 0xFFFFFFFF
sub edx, 0xCA ; вычитаю из edx(0xFFFFFFFF) значение 0xCA
PUTCHAR dl    ; а теперь 0xFFFFFFFF - 0xCA = 0x35 и это символ '5' и мне верно его показывает. 
PUTCHAR 10    ; перевод строки
FINISH        ; завершение программы.
```

В общем вот. Почему так?

Comment: idiv помещает в edx остаток от деления, а он равен нулю, так что у вас в edx оказывается 0

Comment: @Mike тогда бы у меня из 0 вычиталось 0xCA, и даже 6 бы у меня не выводилось...

Comment: @Mike если там все таки 0, разве нет?:) Я сейчас попробовал сделать add edx,0x35, вместо sub и у меня сработало. Тогда в чем смысл вообще cdq если говорится что edx заполнится ffffffff, а после деления станет 0? Или может я чего-то не понял :(

Comment: Вы когда делаете idiv ebx у вас делимое при этом располагается в edx:eax, если cdq не делать и оставить в edx 0, то у вас получиться, что делимое равно +4294967196, а не -100

Comment: 0 - 0xCA = куча FF и 36 на конце (ну и установленный флаг переноса)

Comment: @Mike "0 - 0xCA = куча FF и 36", точно, да, я не так понял, теперь понял. Спасибо )

Comment: @Mike " когда делаете idiv ebx у вас делимое при этом располагается в edx:eax, если cdq не делать и оставить в edx 0, то у вас получиться, что делимое равно +4294967196, а не -100" - а вот это не очень понял ._.

Comment: -100 когда оно edx:eax это FFFFFFFF:FFFFFF9C   А 0x00000000:FFFFFFFF9C это 4294967196

Comment: @Mike 0x00000000:FFFFFF9C, а если это делить на 2, то получается 0x00000000:7FFFFFCE, значит в al теперь 0xCE?

Comment: да. правда вы делите на -2 у себя в коде

Comment: @Mike а если -2, то какой результат будет?

Comment: 0x80000032 вообще на обычном калькуляторе в windows все отлично считается, только переводите его в режим программиста и заодно можете системы счисления переключать

Comment: @Mike прошу прощения, если отвлекаю, я понимаю что 00000010 = 2 и 11111110 = -2, вот, пытаюсь применить это теперь к регистрам и результату, понять что происходит, вообще забыл об этом... Вроде понял, спасибо большое за краткий экскурс :)

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты выполняешь деление `idiv ebx` ты затираешь значение `edx` и он становиться равным нулю.